# Springboot application Controllers Designing

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, spring-restcontroller

i am kind of new with programming, i need help with designig the RestControllers. 
I am trying to design a website Using spring boot, the site supposed to have Guests, Users(registerd), Admin, SuperAdmin. 
would it be true to use the GuestController as the main one, and let all of the other controllers such as Admin,User,Superadmins extend the GuestController?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a more suitable design is to provide a Controller per section (ie Home, News, Search, Admin): each controller is responsible for a section of the web site.
The various user profiles are then used within the controller if you need to differentiate what users can see and do.

There is less code duplication: there is one screen (Search) with one Controller (SearchController) which serves different user profiles. Adding a user profile is straight-forward and does not involve changing the Search code (maybe only adding some extra security in the backend if the new profile can see less or more than the others).

You could use inheritance to define the User Profile: a Guest user is the base profile, but others (Admin) extend it to provide different behaviour.

Hope it helps.